# grit equivalent of git diff

Tags: ruby, rubygems, grit

I am trying to find all the lines of code within the current `git diff` that have been deleted (in the unstaged changes) using the ruby gem grit, i.e. I want to see all the unstaged changes involving deletions. This would be the equivalent of doing `git diff -U0 | grep ^-[^-]` in the shell.

So far I have only been able to figure out how to get the diffs between two commits, or get the names of the files that have been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
diff = @repo.git.diff({:U0 => true}).split( "\n" ).grep( /^-[^-]/ ).join( "\n" )
```

Comment: Not bad. I guess this answers the question in that getting a negative changes only or positive changes only diff with Grit is not possible in any particularly unique way...just by translating the shell into ruby

Comment: @IlyaKavalerov Grit is not fully covered the git calls, show call like this, can be done only by using native call to git.